# Ordering lines of a file numerically Linux/Unix

Tags: linux, file, unix, sorting, command-line

I have two files that I would like to compare. One file orders numbers

```
1    somedata  otherdata
2    somedata  otherdata
3    somedata  otherdata
4    somedata  otherdata
5    somedata  otherdata
6    somedata  otherdata
7    somedata  otherdata
8    somedata  otherdata
Y    somedata  otherdata
Y    somedata  otherdata
```

The other orders

```
1    somedata  otherdata
10    somedata  otherdata
11    somedata  otherdata
12    somedata  otherdata
.
.
.
2    somedata  otherdata
Y   somedata  otherdata
Y   somedata  otherdata
```

It would make my life infinitely easier if I could just sort the second file (Because the first file has a header that I would like to keep in place. Each line of that header begins with a #.) before I run it, so I am comparing apples to apples.

I have tried: sort -n /home/me/file.txt -o /home/me/newfile.txt

And this is ALMOST what I want but it put the letters at the top instead of the bottom. Like this:

```
    Y    somedata  otherdata
    Y    somedata  otherdata
    1    somedata  otherdata
    2    somedata  otherdata
    3    somedata  otherdata
    4    somedata  otherdata
    5    somedata  otherdata
    6    somedata  otherdata
    7    somedata  otherdata
    8    somedata  otherdata
```

What would I do to sort numerically but end up with the letters at the bottom? Or, failing that, is there a way to exclude lines, perhaps, that begin with a certain character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pull out the header lines before running the sort, then add them back in after.  If you have `$n` lines of header, then the following will pipe out everything after it:

```
head -n $n filewithheader.txt >newfile.txt
tail -n $((cat filewithheader.txt| wc -l -$n)) | sort -n >>newfile.txt
```

Now you can sort the files all the same.

If you **really** want to sort alphabetically then numerically, then I'd grep to grab the lines that begin with text into one file, grep the lines that begin with numbers into a second file, sort them separately, then combine.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /tmp/file.list | sort -n | grep -v ^[A-Z] > /tmp/file.list.sorted; grep ^[A-Z] /tmp/file.list  >> /tmp/file.list.sorted
```

This will numerically sort the contents of a file located at /tmp/file.list (exclude any string that begins with a capital letter) and write the contents to /tmp/file.list.sorted. The original file.list is then parsed again, this time grabbing any line beginning with a capital letter and then append the results to the bottom of /tmp/file.list.sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not sort them both using the same algorithm before comparison?  I'm not sure if you can easily force the `sort` utility to do what you ask.

Comment: The first file has some metadata at the top that I would like to keep from mixing in. Is there a way to exclude lines perhaps that begin with a certain character?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are a lot of ways to do this. Here is one way. Substitute your input filename in place of `somedata.txt`.

To send to standard out:

```
cat somedata.txt | grep ^[0-9] | sort -n; cat somedata.txt | grep ^[^0-9] | sort
```

To send to `out.txt`:

```
cat somedata.txt | grep ^[0-9] | sort -n > out.txt; cat somedata.txt | grep ^[^0-9] | sort >> out.txt
```

The above uses grep to separately sort lines that begin with numbers, and lines that don't begin with numbers. This is then piped to either standard out or the file `out.txt`.